# Enemies always spawn diagonally

Tags: javascript, html

The problem I am having here isn't necessarily the code, it's more how the enemies spawn. I have constructed a script that automatically chooses a new 'X' position for the enemies, this event occurs when you have eliminated the previous level of enemies. For me, explaining how I made the hit boxes for the enemies is rather difficult. My main problem is the enemies spawn diagonally next to each other.

I''ll attach an image of how the enemies spawn, and ill chuck the code in for you as well. NOTE: enemies do spawn in different locations, but always seem to be diagonal to each other.

[enemy spawn output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE86z.png)

```
        setInterval(function resetWaveSurviver(){
        if (waveSurviver == true){
            if (enemy1.style.left == '-100px'){
                if (enemy2.style.left == '-100px'){
                    if (enemy3.style.left == '-100px'){
                        if (enemy4.style.left == '-100px'){
                            hits = 0;
                            E1X1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 529) + 1;                                                            
                            E2X1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 521) + 1;                                                                
                            E3X1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 540) + 1;                               
                            E4X1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 530) + 1;
                            E1X2 = E1X1 + 50
                            E1Y1 = E1X1
                            E1Y2 = E1Y1 + 50
                            E2X2 = E2X1 + 50
                            E2Y1 = E2X1
                            E2Y2 = E2Y1 + 50
                            E3X2 = E3X1 + 50
                            E3Y1 = E3X1
                            E3Y2 = E3Y1 + 50
                            E4X2 = E4X1 + 50
                            E4Y1 = E4X1
                            E4Y2 = E4Y1 + 50  
                            enemy1.style.left = '' + E1X1 + 'px' 
                            enemy2.style.left = '' + E2X1 + 'px'
                            enemy3.style.left = '' + E3X1 + 'px'
                            enemy4.style.left = '' + E4X1 + 'px'
                            enemy1.style.top = '' + E1Y1 + 'px'
                            enemy2.style.top = '' + E2Y1 + 'px'
                            enemy3.style.top = '' + E3Y1 + 'px'
                            enemy4.style.top = '' + E4Y1 + 'px'
                            cycle = false;
                            hits = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Could you please share what is the expected result?

Comment: @NikitaSkrebets i did? it is in an image

Comment: that looks diagonal, how do you want them to look?

Comment: And what do the lines `enemy1.style.left == '-100px'` mean? In sense like why is the style is checked at all, and what other values can be there? BTW, the first `if` can be simply `if (waveSurviver)`

Comment: when their left is == to -100px then it means their dead

Comment: @CobaltHex, i want them to be scattered around the screen, not jumbled up next to each other

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They are diagonal because you assign the Y coords same as X: `E1Y1 = E1X1`.
If you want random positions, you need:

```js
E1Y1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxHeight) + 1;
E1Y2 = E1Y1 + 50;
E2Y1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxHeight) + 1;
E2Y2 = E2Y1 + 50;
E3Y1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxHeight) + 1;
E3Y2 = E3Y1 + 50;
E4Y1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxHeight) + 1;
E4Y2 = E4Y1 + 50;
```

For X all the values remain the same.

Comment: All the variables that are called E1X1, E1Y1, E2X1, E2X2, etc, are the hit boxes for the enemy's, but i use the E1X1 to set the X positions for the first enemy. Then the E1Y1 is the Y position of the enemy hitbox.

Comment: @Ben yes, I understand. You have to set the Y variables for each enemy. I wrote only about one because it seems obvious.

Comment: @Ben updated the answer